# Sorting a .txt list by int (weight), by string (name), else by toString()

Tags: java, sorting, compareto

I have to use a compareTo() to sort a .txt list of Animals, Humans, and Fruit by various items.  Right now, I'm trying to work on the Animal class.

I need to use a compareTo() method, which should order by weight within species (biggest comes first), then by name if not an animal, but Named, else by toString();

The .txt is fairly long, but here is a sample from it:

```
human,0.5703735352,jaylen,andrews ,dallas ,,,,,
fruit,0.8782348633,salubura,green,5,,,,,
human,0.3351135254,kaylin,mspherson ,philadelphia ,,,,,
human,0.2774658203,ssott,summings ,houston ,,,,,
human,0.6909179688,phatima,hebert ,new york ,,,,,
human,0.4934692383,vivienne,stuart ,philadelphia ,,,,,
animal,0.6046142578,hamster,Monkey Butt ,46,,,,,
animal,0.4241943359,dog,Sam,60,,,,,
```

And here is my Animal class that I have so far:

```
package domain;

public class Animal implements Named, Comparable<Animal> {

    String species;
    String name;
    int weight;

    /**
     * Convenience constructor
     */
    public Animal(String species, String name, int weight) {
        this.species = species;
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    /**
     * Provide text representation
     */
    public String toString() {
        return name + " (" + species + " / " + weight + ")";
    }

    /**
     * Return our name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Animal t) {
        if (t.name.equals(name)) {
            return species.compareTo(species);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for keeping us informed of your activities. I can't find a question mark in your text so I am not sure what your question is.

Comment: I just have no idea if what I have is what I need in my compareTo method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some pseudo-code for `compareTo` method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Animal t) {
    if(this.weight != t.weight) {
        return this.weight - t.weight;
    } else if(!this.name.equals(t.name)){ // your custom comparision expression
        return who_is_bigger;
    } 
    return 0;  // returns 0 (it seams they are equal) if all conditions are equal 
}
```